# Install UEFI boot loader for second Linux on existing disk

Tags: boot, lvm, luks, uefi

I had an existing Linux on a disk with free space.  The existing `/` partition was too small, so I created new partitions for `/` and separate `/home`, then `rsync`ed files over - from old `/` to new `/` and `/home`.

How do I instruct the existing boot loader to add an option for the new Linux, or install a new EFI/UEFI option alongside the other option?

To make things complicated, the `/` partitions are encrypted with `LUKS`.

Disk layout:

```
# lsblk 
NAME                 MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                    8:0    0 234.3G  0 disk  
├─sda1                 8:1    0   100M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                 8:2    0   556M  0 part  /boot
├─sda3                 8:3    0  21.4G  0 part  
│ └─sda3_crypt       254:0    0  21.4G  0 crypt /
└─sda4                 8:4    0 120.5G  0 part  
  └─lvm_vol          254:1    0 120.5G  0 crypt 
    ├─lvm_swap       254:2    0     8G  0 lvm   
    ├─lvm_linux      254:3    0    22G  0 lvm   
    └─lvm_home       254:4    0  52.8G  0 lvm
```

New (on `lvm_linux`) and old (on `sda3_crypt`) are Ubuntus, the new one `LVM` over `LUKS`, the old one simply `ext4` over `LUKS`.  Currently I cannot boot the new one.

I am sure the question is not specific to Ubuntu (but instead concerns (U)EFI and its boot loaders on LUKS+LVM), therefore I am asking it here.

EDIT: The system boots with (U)EFI which means I need a modified EFI configuration and possibly, files in the `/boot` partition.

Comment: It would be useful to tell which bootloader you are using, with UEFI things get hairy with bootloaders:  Some people use GRUB, others `efibootmgr`, others do not even use a bootloader but use the kernel itself as its own EFI stub (that's me for example).

Comment: @grochmal Thanks, I believe it is `efibootmgr` but I will check and get back to you. What is the fastest way to find out?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html

Comment: @grochmal `efibootmgr` is *not* a bootloader, it's a tool to instruct firmware about bootloader (or a kernel with UEFI stub); again, see the link above, Rod has it all covered.

Comment: @MichaelShigorin - Wow, that's an interesting book, bookmarked.  And very interesting is the fact that `efiootmgr` simply automates what I normally perform by hand.  Thanks.  As of the question, I need to admit that I never used `efibootmgr`.

Comment: @MichaelShigorin OK, so I guess the question is: How do I instruct `efibootmgr` to create the configuration, and how do I prepare the files in `/boot` from the new, unbooted Linux?

Comment: @Ned64 depends on bootloader you intend to use, e.g. GRUB will run `efibootmgr` for you; the rest of details of setting up bootloaders are covered on Rod's site, it's excellent and should have helped you already (sorry for the late reply).  I've actually implemented UEFI support in ALT Linux using it for the most part :)

Answer (score 1):

I you do not strictly need UEFI per se you might be happy to turn your Firmware to use legacy boot instead of UEFI. And then use any traditional boot loader to boot directly your boot partition.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work on this machine. It currently uses EFI and I (just?) need a new configuration based on the non-booted Linux files.